# C# Paste A Picture (In Graphics)

Tags: c#, graphics, image-processing

The thing I want to do is simple. I want to take a picture I already have and paste it into a blank graphics/picture at a certain point, thus expanding my picture's bounds.

To clarify :

```
private static Image PasteImage(Image startimage) //start image is a square of Size(30,30)
    {
        //Create a new picture/graphics with size of (900,900);
        //Paste startimage inside the created picture/graphics at Point (400,450)
        //Return the picture/graphics which should return a square within a square
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the result image to have symmetrical border or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static Image PasteImage(Image startimage)
{
    int width = Math.Max(900, 400 + startimage.Width);
    int height = Math.Max(900, 450 + startimage.Height);
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        g.DrawImage(startimage, 400, 450);
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

It's better to get rid of constants in your code and add a couple of additional params:

```
private static Image PasteImage(Image startimage, Size size, Point startpoint) 
{
    int width = Math.Max(size.Width, startpoint.X + startimage.Width);
    int height = Math.Max(size.Height, startpoint.Y + startimage.Height);
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);        
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        g.Clear(Color.Black);
        g.DrawImage(startimage, new Rectangle(startpoint, startimage.Size));
    }  
    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an image from the startimage using the following

   Graphics.FromImage(startimage);
2. Draw the image where you want to using

   g.DrawImage(...)